# Positioning 360° image to the users direction

Tags: ionic3, aframe, virtual-reality

I'd like to build a VR app that depends on the direction the user is looking at.

My VR content is based on the cardinal points and so if the user looks in the north also the "north-content" should be shown.

I use  to show the 360° image, which should positioned regarding the position an user looks.

My code looks like this

```
<a-scene>
      <a-sky src="../../assets/img/puydesancy.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>
      <a-text font="kelsonsans" value="Sightseeing" width="5" position="-0.75 1.0 -1.5" rotation="0 0 0"></a-text>
</a-scene>
```

The image is a spherical 360° panorama.

Comment: You should provide more details on what exactly you have tried and best would be a working example that illustrates what you are trying to achieve. Your question is vague in details and it will be hard for you to get a concrete answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a component, which will handle the environment, according to the camera's rotation:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("rotationhandler", {
    tick: function() {
      var rotation = this.el.getAttribute("rotation");
      if (rotation.y > 0 && rotation.y < 90) {
        document.querySelector("a-sky").setAttribute("color", "red")
      } else {
        document.querySelector("a-sky").setAttribute("color", "blue")
      }
    }
})
```

So, on `tick` i check the rotation, and when the angle is right, I make some changes. Just throw a modulo on the rotation, so it won't get silly when somebody exceeds 0, or 360 with the rotation.

Check it out on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebvy8wt4/1/).

There is another way, listening for `componentchanged` on the camera, but it is laggy in my opinion.

---

Now, when entering VR mode, the rotation depends on the gyroscope's output values. So it will be corresponding to the north - east etc. like You wanted.